# export mysql database from another computer without the password

Tags: mysql, export

NOTICE I'm not trying to steal anyone's database

My company works with firebird databases and there's this client who already has a system in their company, but they are interested in changing to ours, only if we can export their data from the old system, the problem is that they can't ask for the mysql password and I can't change the root password otherwise their system will stop working.

I have access to the folders and I already copied all the mysql folder to my computer

I have the same version of the client

Comment: Is this a one time export, or will you have to mirror their database over a period of time?

Comment: one time export

Comment: Then can you do a dump of the old system into an SQL file and load it into the new system?

Comment: yes, but to dump I need the root password, I can only do this from my computer

Comment: If you are going to get the data out of the old system, you need the password.  I don't think there is a way around that.

Comment: even if I copy all the files to my computer and reset the root password from my computer?